# Lots of Unnecessary White Space

Tags: formatting, book-design, white-space

**EDIT: I have a smaller MWE.**

I have a document that has lots of footnotes. These footnotes——I believe——have caused unnecessary white space and have made the document quite ugly. Is there a way to get rid of all of this white space? It is throughout the entire document. I have attached my MWE, and some screenshots of the results. I would like to conserve as much space as possible since it will be printed.

It seems that I could save atleast 125 pages by eliminating the extra space. Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}

\setmainlanguage{syriac}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={DejaVu Serif Bold}]{Serto Antioch Bible}

% Make Counters for Chapters and Verses
\newcounter{mychapter}
\newcounter{bibver}
\setcounter{mychapter}{0}
\setcounter{bibver}{0}

% Make Bible Chapter and Verses
\newcommand{\mychaptermark}{}
\newcommand{\bibvermark}{}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{mychapter}% Increment the mychapter counter
  \renewcommand{\mychaptermark}{#1}%
  %\chaptermark{#1 : \bibvermark}% Include the verse number in the chaptermark
  \markboth{#1}{#1}
  {\centering{#1}}% Center the chapter title
}

\newcommand{\bibver}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{bibver}% Increment the bibver counter
  \extramarks{#1}{#1}% Set both left and right marks to #1
  \textsuperscript{\textbf{#1 }}~%
}

% Make Book Title in English and Syriac
\newcommand{\englishtitle}[1]{\centering\LR{#1}}
\newcommand{\syriactitle}[1]{\centering{#1}}


\newcommand{\mymarks}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
{\leftmark} % if equal
{\leftmark--\rightmark}} % if not equal 

% Set the headheight and potentially adjust topmargin
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} % Adjust this value as needed
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.5pt} % Adjust this value as needed

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{} % Clear previous header settings
\fancyhead[CO]{\englishtitle{The Gospel of Matthew}}
\fancyhead[CE]{ܐܘܢܓܠܝܘܢ ܕܡܬܝ}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark:\lastleftxmark –– \rightmark:\firstrightxmark} % Right on odd pages, Left on even pages

\englishtitle{The Gospel of Matthew}

\RL{ܐܘܢܓܠܝܘܢ ܕܡܬܝ}
    
\mychapter{1}

\RL{\bibver{1} ܟ݁ܬ݂ܴܒ݂ܳܐ ܕܻ݁ܝܠܻܝܕ݂ܽܘܬ݂ܷܗ}\footnote{\RL{ܝܺܠܻܝܕ݂ܽܘܬ݂ܴܐ} --
  genealogy} \RL{ܕ݁ܝܶܫܽܘܥ ܡܫܺܝܚܳܐ܆ ܒ݁ܪܷܗ ܕ݁ܕ݂ܰܘܺܝܕ݂܁ ܒ݁ܪܷܗ ܕܱ݁ܐܒ݂ܪܴܗܳܡ܀܀}
\RL{\bibver{2} ܐܱܒ݂ܪܴܗܳܡ ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܻܐܝܣܚܳܩ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܻܝܣܚܳܩ}
  -- Isaac}\RL{܂ ܐܻܝܣܚܳܩ ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܝܰܥܩܽܘܒ݂܂ ܝܰܥܩܽܘܒ݂ ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܻܝܗܽܘܕ݂ܳܐ}\footnote{\RL{ܝܺܗܽܘܕ݂ܳܐ}
  -- Judah} \RL{ܘܠܱܐܚܰܘܗ̄ܝ̈܂ \bibver{3} ܝܺܗܽܘܕ݂ܳܐ ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂
ܠܦ݂ܰܪܨ}\footnote{\RL{ܦܱ݁ܪܨ} -- Perez} \RL{ܘܰܠܙܰܪܚ}\footnote{\RL{ܙܳܪܴܚ} -- Zerah}
\RL{ܡܶܢ ܬܴ݁ܡܳܪ}\footnote{\RL{ܬܴ݁ܡܳܪ} -- Perez}\RL{܂ ܦܱ݁ܪܨ}\footnote{\RL{ܦܱ݁ܪܨ} --
  Perez} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܚܶܨܪܴܘܢ}\footnote{\RL{ܚܶܨܪܾܘܢ} -- Hezron}\RL{܂
ܚܶܨܪܾܘܢ}\footnote{\RL{ܚܶܨܪܾܘܢ} -- Hezron} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܴܐܪܴܡ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܴܪܴܡ}
  -- Ram}\RL{܂ \bibver{4} ܐܴܪܴܡ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܴܪܴܡ} --
  Ram} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܥܰܡܺܝܢܳܕ݂ܳܒ݂}\footnote{\RL{ܥܰܡܺܝܢܳܕ݂ܳܒ݂} -- Aminadab}\RL{܂
ܥܰܡܺܝܢܳܕ݂ܳܒ݂}\footnote{\RL{ܥܰܡܺܝܢܳܕ݂ܳܒ݂} -- Aminadab} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂
ܠܢܰܚܫܳܘܢ}\footnote{\RL{ܢܰܚܫܽܘܢ} -- Nahshon}\RL{܂ ܢܰܚܫܽܘܢ}\footnote{\RL{ܢܰܚܫܽܘܢ}
  -- Nahshon} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܣܰܠܡܳܘܢ}\footnote{\RL{ܣܰܠܡܳܘܢ} -- Salmon}\RL{܂
\bibver{5} ܣܰܠܡܳܘܢ}\footnote{\RL{ܣܰܠܡܳܘܢ} -- Salmon}
\RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܒ݂ܳܥܳܙ}\footnote{\RL{ܒܴ݁ܥܳܙ} -- Boaz} \RL{ܡܶܢ ܪܴܚܳܒ݂}\footnote{\RL{ܪܴܚܳܒ݂}
  -- Rahab}\RL{܂ ܒܴ݁ܥܳܙ}\footnote{\RL{ܒܴ݁ܥܳܙ} -- Boaz} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂
ܠܥܽܘܒ݂ܺܝܕ݂}\footnote{\RL{ܥܽܘܒ݂ܺܝܕ݂} -- Obed} \RL{ܡܶܢ ܪܴܥܽܘܬ݂}\footnote{\RL{ܪܴܥܽܘܬ݂} --
  Ruth}\RL{܂ ܥܽܘܒ݂ܺܝܕ݂}\footnote{\RL{ܥܽܘܒ݂ܺܝܕ݂} -- Obed} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂
ܠܻܐܝܫܰܝ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܻܝܫܰܝ} -- Jesse}\RL{܂ \bibver{6}
ܐܻܝܫܰܝ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܻܝܫܰܝ} -- Jesse} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܕ݂ܰܘܺܝܕ݂ ܡܰܠܟܴ݁ܐ܂ ܕܱ݁ܘܺܝܕ݂ ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂
ܠܱܫܠܷܝܡܳܘܢ}\footnote{\RL{ܫܠܷܝܡܳܘܢ} -- Solomon} \RL{ܡܶܢ ܐܱܢ̄ܬ݁ܬ݂ܷܗ
ܕܾ݁ܐܘܪܻܝܳܐ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܾܘܪܻܝܳܐ} -- Uriah}\RL{܂ \bibver{7}
ܫܠܷܝܡܽܘܢ}\footnote{\RL{ܫܠܷܝܡܳܘܢ} -- Solomon} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂
ܠܱܪܚܰܒ݂ܥܰܡ}\footnote{\RL{ܪܚܰܒ݂ܥܰܡ} -- Rehoboam}\RL{܂ ܪܚܰܒ݂ܥܰܡ}\footnote{\RL{ܪܚܰܒ݂ܥܰܡ}
  -- Rehoboam} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܱܐܒ݂ܺܝܳܐ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܱܒ݂ܺܝܳܐ} -- Abijah}\RL{܂
ܐܱܒ݂ܺܝܳܐ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܱܒ݂ܺܝܳܐ} -- Abijah} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܴܐܣܳܐ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܴܣܳܐ} --
  Asa}\RL{܂ \bibver{8} ܐܴܣܳܐ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܴܣܳܐ} -- Asa}
\RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܝܳܗܽܘܫܳܦ݂ܳܛ}\footnote{\RL{ܝܳܗܽܘܫܳܦ݂ܳܛ} -- Jehoshaphat}\RL{܂
ܝܳܗܽܘܫܳܦ݂ܳܛ}\footnote{\RL{ܝܳܗܽܘܫܳܦ݂ܳܛ} -- Jehoshaphat} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂
ܠܝܽܘܪܴܡ}\footnote{\RL{ܝܽܘܪܴܡ} -- Joram}\RL{܂ ܝܽܘܪܴܡ}\footnote{\RL{ܝܽܘܪܴܡ} --
  Joram} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܥܽܘܙܺܝܳܐ}\footnote{\RL{ܥܽܘܙܺܝܳܐ} -- Uzziah}\RL{܂
\bibver{9} ܥܽܘܙܺܝܳܐ}\footnote{\RL{ܥܽܘܙܺܝܳܐ} -- Uzziah}
\RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܝܽܘܬ݂ܴܡ}\footnote{\RL{ܝܽܘܬ݂ܴܡ} -- Jotham}\RL{܂ ܝܽܘܬ݂ܴܡ}\footnote{\RL{ܝܽܘܬ݂ܴܡ}
  -- Jotham} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܴܐܚܳܙ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܴܚܳܙ} -- Ahaz}\RL{܂
ܐܴܚܳܙ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܴܚܳܙ} -- Ahaz} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܚܶܙܰܩܝܳܐ}\footnote{\RL{ܚܶܙܰܩܝܳܐ} --
  Hezekiah}\RL{܂ \bibver{10} ܚܶܙܰܩܝܳܐ}\footnote{\RL{ܚܶܙܰܩܝܳܐ}
  -- Hezekiah} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܱܡܢܰܫܶܐ}\footnote{\RL{ܡܢܰܫܶܐ} -- Manasseh}\RL{܂
ܡܢܰܫܶܐ}\footnote{\RL{ܡܢܰܫܶܐ} -- Manasseh} \RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂
ܠܱܐܡܽܘܢ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܱܡܽܘܢ} -- Amon}\RL{܂ܐܱܡܽܘܢ}\footnote{\RL{ܐܱܡܽܘܢ} -- Amon}
\RL{ܐܱܘܠܷܕ݂ ܠܝܽܘܫܺܝܳܐ}\footnote{\RL{ܝܽܘܫܺܝܳܐ} -- Josiah}
\end{document}
```

[[image: Lots of space][1]]
[image: Lots of extra space]

Comment: Like your other question, you've not given us enough to really help you.  Copy everything over to a new project.  Paste enough of `04_Gospel of Matthew.tex` to get these two pages, and delete all of the `\include` commands.  Then start deleting any commands that don't affect the white space problem.  You should be able to get things down to about 30 lines that you can paste here in its entirety.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated the question.

Comment: Not an answer, but loading `geometry` and then sneaking behind its back and changing the page layout manually is at best pointless. At worst, the two sets of directions will conflict and mess things up. Also check the transcript for `fancyhdr` warnings about head height. 12pt usually requires adjustment. You can also add `verbose` to `geometry` to get more information about its calculations.